# Selenium Python not able to select value from drop down for Amazon product detail screen

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate an add to cart operation for amazon products, one issue I ran into is I was not able to simulate click dropdown menu using selenium in python. Here is my current code (ignore imports) :

```
            select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("native_dropdown_selected_size_name"))
            print("select = ", select)
            for o in select.options:
                if o.text == '12':
                    print("found")
            select.select_by_visible_text("12")
```

In my code, I'm trying to select the size 12 option from menu dropdown. From the print statement I can tell the dropdown is found and size 12 is also there but the select_by_visible_text doesn't seem to work.

Another option I have tried is:

```
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='native_dropdown_selected_size_name']/option[text()='12']").click()
```

which also doesn't seem to work.

Here is the product I'm experimenting on: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07KRY1JPK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KRY1JPK). The color option is there by default so the issue is with the size selection.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I'm able to solve the issue by clicking on the span tag (sibling after the select) and the a tag that is hidden under span to make a selection. The original select tag does not work for some reason. My guess is it is for native only.

Comment: Have you tried  `select.select_by_value("12")`

Comment: Just tried that, doesn't work either.

Comment: @zzzzz_2 could you please share the solution that you came up with. i am also stuck with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The `options` text contains space, use [`normalize-space`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example6.html):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='native_dropdown_selected_size_name']/option[normalize-space(text())='12']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is not fixing the issue. I think the text option can be found correctly, but cannot be selected properly. I thought it might be the option being invisible so I have tried this: [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver), but still not working.

Comment: @zzzzz_2 I've tried and worked for me, what error did you get?

Comment: It didn't give any error but it also doesn't work. For some reason the select element doesn't seem to be interactable. So my fix is to simulate actual user behavior and click the span (sibling element with the select) that triggers the js snippet.